# Why is my spring-cloud-config server on aws intermittently not responding?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, spring-cloud-config, amazon-elb

I am running a spring cloud config server on aws which is just a docker container running a spring boot app. It is reading properties from a git repo. Our client applications read config from the server on startup and intermittently at runtime. About a third of the time, the client apps will timeout when pulling config at startup, causing the app to crash. At runtime, the apps seem to succeed 4 out of 5 times, though they will just use existing config if a request fails.

I am using an ec2 instance behind an alb which handles ssl termination. I was orignally using a t3.micro, but upgraded to an m5.large guessing that the t3 class may not support continuous availability.

The alb required 2 subnets, so I created a second with nothing in it initially. I am unsure if the alb will attempt to route to the second subnet at some point, which could be causing the failures. The target group is using a health check which returns correctly, but idk enough about alb's to rule out round-robin'ing to an empty subnet. I attempted to create a second ec2 instance to parallel my first config server in the second subnet. however, I was unable to ssh into the second instance even though it's using the same security group and config as the first. I'm not sure why that failed, but i'm guessing there is something else wrong with my setup.

All infrastructure was deployed with terraform, which I have included below.

resources.tf

```
provider "aws" {
  region  = "us-east-2"
  version = ">= 2.38.0"
}

data "aws_ami" "amzn_linux" {
  most_recent = true
  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["amzn2-ami-hvm-2.0.*-x86_64-gp2"]
  }
  filter {
    name   = "virtualization-type"
    values = ["hvm"]
  }
  owners = ["137112412989"]
}


resource "aws_vpc" "config-vpc" {
  cidr_block           = "10.0.0.0/16"
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
  enable_dns_support   = true
}

resource "aws_security_group" "config_sg" {
  name        = "config-sg"
  description = "http, https, and ssh"

  vpc_id = aws_vpc.config-vpc.id

  ingress {
    from_port   = 9000
    to_port     = 9000
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  ingress {
    from_port   = 8080
    to_port     = 8080
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  ingress {
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  ingress {
    from_port   = 443
    to_port     = 443
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  ingress {
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "subnet-alpha" {
  cidr_block        = cidrsubnet(aws_vpc.config-vpc.cidr_block, 3, 1)
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.config-vpc.id
  availability_zone = "us-east-2a"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "subnet-beta" {
  cidr_block        = cidrsubnet(aws_vpc.config-vpc.cidr_block, 3, 2)
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.config-vpc.id
  availability_zone = "us-east-2b"
}

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "config-vpc-ig" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.config-vpc.id
}

resource "aws_route_table" "config-vpc-rt" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.config-vpc.id
  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.config-vpc-ig.id
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "subnet-association-alpha" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.subnet-alpha.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.config-vpc-rt.id
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "subnet-association-beta" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.subnet-beta.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.config-vpc-rt.id
}

resource "aws_alb" "alb" {
  name            = "config-alb"
  subnets         = [aws_subnet.subnet-alpha.id, aws_subnet.subnet-beta.id]
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.config_sg.id]
}

resource "aws_alb_target_group" "alb_target_group" {
  name     = "config-tg"
  port     = 9000
  protocol = "HTTP"
  vpc_id   = aws_vpc.config-vpc.id
  health_check {
    enabled  = true
    path     = "/actuator/health"
    port     = 9000
    protocol = "HTTP"
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "config_server_alpha" {
  ami                         = data.aws_ami.amzn_linux.id
  instance_type               = "m5.large"
  vpc_security_group_ids      = [aws_security_group.config_sg.id]
  key_name                    = "config-ssh"
  subnet_id                   = aws_subnet.subnet-alpha.id
  associate_public_ip_address = true
}

resource "aws_instance" "config_server_beta" {
  ami                         = data.aws_ami.amzn_linux.id
  instance_type               = "m5.large"
  vpc_security_group_ids      = [aws_security_group.config_sg.id]
  key_name                    = "config-ssh"
  subnet_id                   = aws_subnet.subnet-beta.id
  associate_public_ip_address = true
}

resource "aws_alb_target_group_attachment" "config-target-alpha" {
  target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.alb_target_group.arn
  target_id        = aws_instance.config_server_alpha.id
  port             = 9000
}

resource "aws_alb_target_group_attachment" "config-target-beta" {
  target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.alb_target_group.arn
  target_id        = aws_instance.config_server_beta.id
  port             = 9000
}

resource "aws_alb_listener" "alb_listener_80" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_alb.alb.arn
  port              = 80
  default_action {
    type = "redirect"
    redirect {
      port        = 443
      protocol    = "HTTPS"
      status_code = "HTTP_301"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_alb_listener" "alb_listener_8080" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_alb.alb.arn
  port              = 8080
  default_action {
    type = "redirect"
    redirect {
      port        = 443
      protocol    = "HTTPS"
      status_code = "HTTP_301"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_alb_listener" "alb_listener_https" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_alb.alb.arn
  port              = 443
  protocol          = "HTTPS"
  ssl_policy        = "ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08"
  certificate_arn   = "arn:..."
  default_action {
    target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.alb_target_group.arn
    type             = "forward"
  }
}
```

config server

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
public class ConfigserverApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigserverApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: local

---
spring:
  profiles: local, default, cloud
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: ...
          searchPaths: '{application}/{profile}'
          username: ...
          password:...
  security:
    user:
      name: admin
      password: ...

server:
  port: 9000

management:
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always
  info:
    git:
      mode: FULL
```

bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: config-server

encrypt:
  key: |
    -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
    ...
    -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: Your example is missing some key bits and also has some typos in it so is presumably not exactly the code you are using and having issues with. It's always useful if a question includes a full [mcve] that reproduces the issue to help answerers see where to look.

Comment: updated tf. not much in the app files, but i've added them as well. that's just bundled into a docker image, then run w/ `docker run ...` on the ec2 instance. The application is boilerplate, which is why i don't think it's the issue. did fix the second instance by adding a route table association for that subnet, but i don't think the second instance should even be necessary if the health check is returning 200 for the first instance.